# Disable Button on Access Form Based on Drop Down Selection

Tags: ms-access

I have an Access form with a couple of buttons that I want to disable based on the drop down selection of another field.

When the Status dropdown is set to "Closed" I want the "Add" buttons to be disabled, disappear, or inactive for people to use. I also need the buttons to be reactivated if the job is reopened.

I thought I would use the OnCurrent attribute but so far I can't figure out the correct code to make it happen.

Thank you.

[image: Example]

Comment: What have you tried? Edit question to show attempted code. Probably need to put code in form Current as well as combobox AfterUpdate events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place code in form Current as well as combobox AfterUpdate events.

`Me.buttonname.Enabled = Me.comboboxname <> "Closed"`

Or use Visible property if you prefer.

Comment: This was the solution for me. It was also the easiest to understand from many of the other attempts I've made.